# Tensorflow tf.train.Saver saves suspiciously large .ckpt files?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm working with a reasonably sized net (1 convolutional layer, 2 fully connected layers). Every time I save variables using `tf.train.Saver`, the `.ckpt` files are half a gigabyte each of disk space (512 MB to be exact). Is this normal? I have a Caffe net with the same architecture that requires only a 7MB `.caffemodel` file. Is there a particular reason why Tensorflow saves such large file sizes?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share more details of your model architecture, ideally in the form of a set of `tf.Variable` declarations?

Answer (score 6):

Hard to tell how large your net is from what you've described -- the number of connections between two fully connected layers scales up quadratically with the size of each layer, so perhaps your net is quite large depending on the size of your fully connected layers.

If you'd like to save space in the checkpoint files, you could replace this line:

`saver = tf.train.Saver()`

with the following:

`saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables())`

By default, `tf.train.Saver()` saves all variables in your graph -- including the variables created by your optimizer to accumulate gradient information. Telling it to save only *trainable* variables means it will save only the weights and biases of your network, and discard the accumulated optimizer state. Your checkpoints will probably be a lot smaller, with the tradeoff that it you may experience slower training for the first few training batches after you resume training, while the optimizer re-accumulates gradient information. It doesn't take long at all to get back up to speed, in my experience, so personally, I think the tradeoff is worth it for the smaller checkpoints.

Comment: Hi, I wonder to know, if the network contains BN layers, what should I do? Because the mean and variance are variables, but they are not trainable. If I only save tf.tf.trainable_variables(), when I restore the model, tensorflow can't find the BN mean parameters......

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try (in Tensorflow 1.0):

```
saver.save(sess, filename, write_meta_graph=False)
```

which doesn't save meta Graph information.
See:
 https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver
 https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph

Comment: but the downside is that you have to create variable manually first, then you can restore them. Otherwise it will report error as it cannot find the proper variable.

Comment: Do you mean tensorflow1.0 save model small? Because I use tensorflow 1.3, can the model size is larger  than tensorflow1.0 I saved......

Answer (score 0):

Typically you only save `tf.global_variables()` (which is shorthand for `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)`, i.e. the collection of global variables). This collection is meant to include variables which are necessary for restoring the state of the model, so things like current moving averages for batch normalization, the global step, the states of the optimizer(s) and, of course, the `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection. Variables of more temporary nature, such as the gradients, are collected in `LOCAL_VARIABLES` and it is usually not necessary to store them and they might take up a lot of disk space.